# How To Create Query In RDLC Report Using VB 2010

Tags: sql, vb.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I want to create a report with **.rdlc**, in this case i want to join some table and put the result in table on the rdlc file. I got confused, coz there is no place to put my query in the report.
Did i have to write some coding to create the report, so i can use the query?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suggest downloading SAP Crystal Reports (http://www.crystalreports.com/). If you are using SQL Server, use Business Intelligence to create the report through the server. The report viewer currently installed with Visual Studio is not user friendly.